# On Android, how to check validity of currency code?

Tags: android, currency

In the SDK documentation, the Currency.getInstance(String currencyCode) should trigger an IllegalArgumentException if the currencyCode is not ISO 4217 but I tried to use this as a currency code validator in the case of a user entering a currency not in a prefilled Spinner.

But in my tests, the Exception does not trigger, it returns me an instance of Currency with the string passed as symbol.

Is there a way to validate a currency code in Android?

```
String currency = mCustomCurrency.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
try {
    Currency.getInstance(currency);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    if (errMsg.length() > 0)
        errMsg.append("\n");
    errMsg.append(getString(R.string.bad_format_for_currency));
    res = false;
}
```

Comment: Post your test, maybe it's not doing the right thing?

Comment: I've put crappy strings like "xieeuuii" that are definitively not ISO 4217

Comment: Yeah I figured that but you say the exception is not thrown in your test, so perhaps your test isn't setup to fail properly if your test is passing.

Comment: I've edited my question with the code as I can't figure out how to formatted code in comments (too late over here :p )

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote this and it works (fails) fine.

```
import java.util.Currency;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class CurrencyTest extends TestCase {

    public void test_ExpectExceptionWithInvalidCurrencyCode() {
        try {
            Currency curr = Currency.getInstance("BLABLABLA");
            fail("Expected IllegalArgumentException");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown, as expected.");
        }
    }

}
```

So in your test what are you doing with `res`?

Comment: Are you testing in Android env ?

Comment: Kinda, it's in my Android project using the Android JUnit test launcher, it's not run using the InstrumentationTestRunner since it's not related to any activity or UI. Shouldn't make a difference anyway since it's still just a unit test.

Comment: The fact is that with a breakpoint, I don't enter in the catch clause

Comment: same here - this works as expected when running junit tests, but IllegalArgumentException is not thrown when run on an Android device